# Handling __dirname in node module

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm using the package `pdfkit`, which itself uses `fontkit`. 
Generating PDF files works fine when running the containing express app in develop mode, but resolving some paths seems not to work when the application is bundled with webpack.

I already filed an [issue](https://github.com/devongovett/fontkit/issues/67), but my question is more a general one:

If an npm packages uses `__dirname` somewhere to access a relative path, how must I configure webpack to consider it?

Here's my current configuration:

```
var Webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
var mainPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'app.js');

var config = {

  target: 'node',
  entry: mainPath,
  output: {
    path: buildPath,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  node: {
    console: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    dns: 'empty',
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015']
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.json$/,
            loader: 'json'
        },
        ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

I think the line causing the issue in fontkit is:

```
var trie = new UnicodeTrie(require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname + '/data.trie'));
```

Comment: in terms of dynamic build only can you represent the file structure from where you are trying to link the main server.

Comment: @GandalftheWhite what exactly does that mean in regard to my question?

Comment: as in your whole directory structure. Where the server is and from where dynamically you would like to pick something up in the server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set __dirname to true in your webpack.config

`node: { 
    __dirname: true 
}`